# How to look for occurences of chr(1) - chr(47) in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to find all occurences of chr(1) - chr(47) in the database, as they mess up my data, but for a reason unknown i get errors while trying.

code is really simple :

```
declare
    v_sql varchar(300);
    match_count integer;
BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..37
  LOOP
  
  dbms_output.put_line(l_counter);
  v_sql := 'select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '|| '''%' || chr(l_counter) || '%''' ;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  execute immediate v_sql
  into match_count;
  dbms_output.put_line(match_count);
  
  END LOOP;

end;
```

/

when i try chr47 onwards it works, but lower values give me error:

SCRIPT OUTPUT:
1
Error at line 1
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DBMS OUTPUT

1 0 2 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 3 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 4 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 5 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 6 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 7 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 8 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 9 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%  %' 0 10 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '% %' 0 11 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 12 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 13 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '% %' 0 14 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 15 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 16 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 17 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 18 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 19 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 20 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 21 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 22 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 23 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 24 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 25 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 26 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 27 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 28 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 29 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 30 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 31 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%' 0 32 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '% %' 0 33 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%!%' 0 34 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%"%' 0 35 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%#%' 0 36 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%$%' 0 37 select count(*) from CD_WELL where WELL_ID LIKE '%%%' 9452

Can anyone help me here? thanks

Answer (score 2):

With `LIKE`, you need to escape the `%` character (and the `_` character) when you are trying to match it as a literal rather than as a wildcard. (You also do not need dynamic SQL.)

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(300);
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..40
  LOOP
    select count(*)
    into   match_count
    from   CD_WELL
    where  WELL_ID LIKE '%' || CASE CHR(l_counter)
                               WHEN '%' THEN '\%'
                               WHEN '_' THEN '\_'
                               ELSE CHR(l_counter)
                               END || '%' ESCAPE '\';
  
    dbms_output.put_line(l_counter || ' = ' || match_count);
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

or use `INSTR`:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(300);
  match_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..40
  LOOP
    select count(*)
    into   match_count
    from   CD_WELL
    where  INSTR(WELL_ID, CHR(l_counter)) > 0;
  
    dbms_output.put_line(l_counter || ' = ' || match_count);
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aa36763384ba76b090c2da6555b14810)*